# Rounding all numbers but keep the sum

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have 4 records as follows:

```
CASH    
========    
1993.772
5015.572
996.884
1993.772
```

These numbers add up to `10000.00`. Now I want to round all these numbers to two decimal places, but keep the sum as `10000.00`.

In the above example, if I remove the last digit, the sum of the numbers will be `9999.99` and not `10000.00`, but something like this would still add up to `10000.00`:

```
CASH    
========    
1993.78   <- changed from 1993.77 to 1993.78
5015.57
996.88
1993.77
```

Any easy way to do it?

Comment: Please show us your expected result.

Comment: @GMB updated the question

Answer (score 4):

This is challenging.  Here is one method:

```
select t.*,
       round(cash, 2),
       (case when row_number() over (order by cash desc) = 1
             then sum(cash) over () - sum(round(cash, 2)) over (order by cash rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
             else round(cash, 2)
        end)
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d0b12a0f77f8c682a85d632943bf7460) is a db<>fiddle.

Basically, this rounds all the values to two decimal places except the biggest one.  For that one, it subtracts the sum of the rounded values from the total.

Note:  This adds the extra to the largest value.  It could round the smallest value, but I think rounding the largest is safer (a smaller incremental change to the value).  If you have other columns to specify the ordering, then the "first" or "last" column can be chosen instead.

Comment: hm for the last columns I am getting 
`
null,
9003.120,
7009.350,
5015.580
`

Comment: @Yar . . . I fixed the logic and added a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate all of the values up into a sum and into an array, then unroll the array back into their separate rows.

```sql
SELECT
  unnest(array_agg(round(ct.cash, 2))) AS cash,
  round(sum(ct.cash), 2) AS total
FROM cash_table AS ct;
```

Result

```
  cash  |  total
--------+---------
1993.77 | 10000.00
5015.57 | 10000.00
996.88  | 10000.00
1993.77 | 10000.00
```

Comment: The sum of the `cash` values is **not** 10000.

Comment: It is when summing the pre-rounded numbers. Out of curiosity, what do you think their sum is?

Comment: That is the whole point of OPs question. OP wants the rounded numbers to add to 10000, the same as the pre-rounded numbers do. Just looking at the last digits (7,7,8,7) you can immediately tell the result does not end in 0.